# How to make a rocketdock / OSX style launch bar using Delphi

Tags: delphi, toolbar

I'd like to make a tool bar with icons that get's bigger when you mouse over them. I don't mind reinventing the wheel, but if anyone can suggest a good:

1. Image Format (not sure bitmaps'll work here and not sure how to do Vectors)
2. Existing Control (pay or free, so long as I can use it in a close source app)
3. Container class (is TPanel sufficient?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not used it yet personally, but maybe check out TMS TAdvSmoothDock rather than reinventing wheel..?

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advsmoothdock.asp

Comment: Even awesomer is the fact that Embarcadero is giving out free candy http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39481

Answer (score 1):

There is some sample code doing exactly this on the delphi.about.com website.

The link below shows the code as well as an example image of the dock while running.

http://delphi.about.com/od/fullcodeprojects/a/mac-doc-launch.htm

I don't know if the code is D2009 compatible or not, but even if it isn't the code shouldn't be that hard to bring forward.  I would think anyways.

HTH,

Ryan.

Comment: the link you have provided is not working anymore !! do u have that example ^^

Comment: @user3374161 

https://web.archive.org/web/20130512010746/http://delphi.about.com/od/fullcodeprojects/a/mac-doc-launch.htm

you can download the source code from that page.